# multiplying polynomials

Tags: python

how to create a function `multiply(p1,p2)` that multiplies two polynomials of the form `[(1,1),(-1,0)],[(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)]` i.e, `(x - 1) * (x^2 + x + 1)` to produce the result  `[(1, 3),(-1, 0)]` i.e, `x^3 - 1` involving dictionaries and without invoking standard library functions. I have coded for the addition of two polynomials, but this one seems to be a tedious task

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look to [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial multiplication is discrete convolution of two sequences. You can use [`convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) from numpy or open a textbook and implement the formula (also given in the `convolve` documentation with inf instead of the maximum degree of the two polynomials).

Answer (score 0):

What seems tedious about it?

I would suggest starting out by looking at the math some, and then doing each term in the addition one by one, perhaps adding them up using your previous addition-code.

So, for each term in the first polynomial, multiply it by each term in the second polynomial, and add them all up.

The multiplication of one such term by another (say `(a,b)` by `(c,d)`), would have the coefficients multiplied, and the exponents added (to give `(a*c,b+d)`). 
As in the example, the term `-1*x^2 = -x^2`, and `x*x^2 = x^3`.